How can I access DOM of a website using phantomjs
I am trying get all the anchor tags in a website using phantomjs. My code was working fine when I used it with https://example.com. But when I changed it into an Angular website(Angular 16), I realized that the html that I am getting is not DOM. I only getting the code inside index.html. I even got the comments inside index.html
Here is my code.
const getWebsiteData = async (url) => {
  const instance = await phantom.create();
  const page = await instance.createPage();

  console.log('URL::', url);

  const status = await page.open(url);
  console.log('STATUS::', status);

  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.error('Failed to load the page');
    instance.exit();
    return;
  }

  const content = await page.property('content');
  console.log('CONTENT::', content);

  const links = await page.evaluate(function() {
    var anchorTags = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    var linksArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < anchorTags.length; i++) {
      linksArray.push({
        href: anchorTags[i].href,
        text: anchorTags[i].innerText || anchorTags[i].href
      });
    }
    return linksArray;
  });

  console.log('LINKS::', links);

  instance.exit();
  return { url, status, content, links }
};

This is body of the html I got (from content) when I used url of a website built in Angular 16
<body class="mat-typography">
<app-root></app-root>

<!-- Comments from index.html -->
<script src="runtime.330007b6045bd5f7.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="polyfills.25307c7f841666c3.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="main.f07338220f1c2c93.js" type="module"></script>

</body></html>

as you can see, I can't access components inside <app-root></app-root>
Is there any way that I can access the DOM instead?
If it is a Yes, explain how can I do it. If it is a No, if you can explain what is the reason, it would be helpful.

NB : I know phantomjs is deprecated long ago, but I am looking for a way to do it without migrating to other alternatives.

I tried this line var page = require('webpage').create();, sample code in most of the documentations. but that was an error. I was expecting the entire DOM code, not just initial page.

PhantomJS is Suspended, https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344, any users should consider switching to a more up2date testing application.
